# How to create Teams with Powershell with a CSV file

Tags: powershell, csv, microsoft-teams

I have to manually create Teams, so i thought i would be a good idea to make this proces automatic. The code keeps giving me the error "Cannot validate argument on parameter "DisplayName. The argument is Null or empty".

It is for Windows Server 2012 R2, I think it does recognize the csv file because this is the only error that i'm getting

[This is my CSV file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p0cQY.png)

```
$datacsv = import-csv C:\Users\$$$$$\Desktop\test.csv
Import-Module MicrosoftTeams
foreach ($data in $datacsv)
{ 
    $cred = Get-Credential
    Connect-MicrosoftTeams -Credential $cred

    $teamname = $data.TeamsName
    $owner = $data.Owners 
    $accestype = $data.TeamType
    $member = $data.Members

    $group = New-team -DisplayName $teamname -Owner $owner -AccesType $accestype
    Add-TeamUser -User $member -GroupId $group.GroupId -DisplayName $teamname
    Add-Teamuser -User $owner -GroupId $group.GroupId -DisplayName $owner
}
```

I expected that the teams would indeed create but this didnt happen.

Sorry for the bad English, my writing is pretty bad.

Comment: Please ensure that the `TeamsName` column exist in the CSV (should it perhaps be TeamName)

Comment: "Normally", you would have one column per header by default when you open a CSV in excel. You either have a different default delimiter or there is something else not right about the data in the file. Do you perhaps have quotes around each row? You should be able to test `$teamname` by just typing `$teamname` after it is assigned in your script. I think seeing that output would go a long way here.

Comment: Set `$VerbosePreference = 'Continue'` and see if the verbose output gives you any more information.

Comment: @Poellie - You need to correct the logic of reading CSV. Due to this DisplayName is read blank. This logic works well when you have only one property. Just keep only TeamName in CSV and this works. one more observation - There is spelling mistake in -AccesType, it should be -AccessType.